# Getting of array of controls returning empty array on first submit

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have html like:

```
<form method="post" id="volunteer" name="volunteer" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">   
<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
</br>

<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
</br>

<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code behind, I'm trying to get all Rank values from all controls:

```
$rank = $_POST['Rank'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rank);
echo "</pre>";

$output = "";
foreach($rank as $selected_value)
{
    if($selected_value != "0") {
        $output .= $selected_value . "<br />";
    }
}
```

But on first submit my **$output** is empty. If I click "Back" on browser and re-submit the form, I actually get not-empty array and output.

Please advice!

Comment: Where's your form wrapping elements?

Comment: is `print_r($rank)` giving you anything?

Comment: not on the first submit, but second time if I re-submit the form

Comment: did you write php code before or after the html form?

Comment: why do you use $PHP_SELF?

Comment: Note: you can't have multiple elements with the same id in HTML, **id attributes should be unique**

Comment: @MichaelVidal removing it does not help. Bibaswann Bandyopadhyay, yes, the form itself is huge and I have a lot of PHP before and after HTML form

Comment: sometimes the php action after the html form creates the problem

Comment: @koala_dev changing the ID's to be unique helped! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @koala_dev in comment section, changing the id's "Rank" to unique does fix the issue.

Comment: Note that this won't be an issue on all browser implementations... Which makes it a browser compatibility issue, not an all-out bug.

Comment: Worked in Chrome for me.

Comment: Yes. I'm just making sure you know that it works in some browsers without the change to unique ID's. It may be useful info in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make

```
<form method="post" id="volunteer" name="volunteer" action="">
```

I have removed PHP_SELF

And change submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_btn">
```

I hope this will work

Comment: You have written the PHP code same page itself, right ? Its working fine for me ( Firefox )

Answer (score 0):

Try to write on `action=""` the name of the file where is your php code,like this:

```
<form method="post" id="volunteer" name="volunteer" action="name-of-your-php-file.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tested this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Rank'])) {
        $rank = $_POST['Rank'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($rank);
        echo "</pre>";

        $output = "";
        foreach($rank as $selected_value)
        {
            if($selected_value != "0") {
                $output .= $selected_value . "<br />";
            }
        }
            echo $output;
    }

?>
```

And it actually works for me.

The only change I did is this:

```
<form method="post" id="volunteer" name="volunteer" action="./">
```

However, this is probably NOT your case.

Try changing your action in this way:

1. Try "./" if your script is an "index.php" or, in general, the main page.
2. Try "", even if I don't think it may work.
3. Put your page name like "myscript.php".

The problem is surely there. Can you please tell us what's the structure of your directory? Where is your file located? What is the file position in htdocs?

ps: my output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Medium Priority
    [1] => High Priority
    [2] => Medium Priority
)
Medium Priority
High Priority
Medium Priority
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this and it works on my machine. Name of the file is sample.php Maybe you can copy-paste to see if this works

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["Rank"]))
{
    $rank = $_POST['Rank'];
    $output = "";
    foreach($rank as $selected_value)
    {
        if($selected_value != "0") {
            $output .= $selected_value . "<br />";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
<form action="sample.php" method="post">
<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
</br>

<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
</br>

<select name="Rank[]" id="Rank">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="High Priority">High Priority</option>
    <option value="Medium Priority">Medium Priority</option>
    <option value="Low Priority">Low Priority</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I've gone ahead and tested it on my own server. It works fine. So here are the possible issues for you personally:

1) You're misunderstanding the way a form works. Remember that when you first load the page, the $_POST['Rank'] variable **will not be populated**. Only when you submit the data, will the $_POST['Rank'] global variable be populated.

2) You're not actually outputting the `$output` variable in your example code. That may just be an omission for Stack Overflow, but if you want to see your stringified output then you need to do this.

3) ID's could be messing up the data for specific browsers. Change them to be unique on the HTML elements

Comment: thank you, but I have fixed it by renaming controls to unique ID's